# is XG-601M "linuxable"?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

I've got laptop with wlan card XG-601M. Is it able to cooperate with linux or not?

Answer (score 1):

when in doubt, download a live cd, boot from that and check if linux recognizes the card and sets up the connection for you.

Comment: This would have made a great comment.

Comment: I did it. But I'm not sure if my card socket is working correctly. So I asked.